# Error after installing ngx-datetime-picker in angular 7

Tags: angular, datetimepicker

guys. I installed ngx-datetime-picker and when I run ng build --prod I've got this error.
[Here is my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qry32.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a problem with ngx-datetime-picker library. Try using the below

```
npm install ngx-datetime-picker@2.1.3 --save
```

or try disabling the --aot flag

Comment: Thank you so much. You're solution works. Have a nice day.

Comment: Please mark this reply as accepted answer Click on the up Arrow

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when the version of your Angular project isn't compatible with the version of the npm library you are trying to install.

What I will suggest you do is to go to your  **angular.json** file and change buildOptimizer to **false**.

Comment: I solved the issue. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Good. You're welcome.